# Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException'

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

My ASP.NET Core application is throwing an exception:

> Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in Pipelines.Sockets.Unofficial.dll
>
> Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
>
> Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in System.Net.Sockets.dll

but all these exceptions are not affecting the application  performance and I can't figure out the reason of the exceptions.

Should I ignore them or there is a way to find solution?

I need a solution how to figure the exception reason or if I can ignore it

Comment: I'm afraid you are a new member of an application maintaining team, you might ask other team members that if you need to set up some other configurations to make the whole app running... Maybe we are failed to connect to redis server? Or something else?

Comment: No iam not  a new member. The whole application is working normally and the connection to redis fine and  all functionality is working.

Comment: ok, we might need to debug the code or add more logs and try to address the line-code where throw the exception...